# how to remove tags from the returned php result?

Tags: php, android

in my android app i return some data from my MYSQL data base through a php script and if the returned result was null : it will be returned to my app in this format :

```
result<br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: output in C:\wamp\www\y.php on line <i>16</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>368264</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\y.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\y.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr></table></font>" not exist"
```

this word : " not exist"   i added  it in my php through an if statement to check result  if its null, i want to replace it by string value which is  " not exist" , and in my app i will handle  it rather than handling  null value which will cause  JSON Exception since the null value or value in this foramt cant be parsed to JSON array 
my question is : how i can remove all the tags returned with the result ?  if the $output was null i replaced it with  " not exist" but it didnt return  in JSON format as in case it has value ,why  ?  please help me since i am new in php...

**php code**

```
$name=$_REQUEST['Name'];          
     mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass")or OnError('database connection failed', mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("MYDB")or OnError('database selection failed', mysql_error($mysql));
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
   $sql=mysql_query("select  burnedCalories   from Exercise where  Name='$name' ");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
   $output[]=$row;
   if (is_null($output))  // if the exercise name not exist the result will be null
    {                                
      $output = ' not exist';
    }
    print(json_encode($output));
     mysql_close();
    define('DEBUG_DETAILS', true);
    function onError($msg, $details) {
    $msg = array(
    'status'=>'error',
    'message'=>$msg);
if ( defined('DEBUG_DETAILS') && DEBUG_DETAILS ) {
    $msg['details'] = $details;
}
die(json_encode($msg));}
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
$text = strip_tags($text);
```

for this. it's exactly what you need.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

Few things to keep in mind, some of these are opinions but they may help:

```
<?php
// Constants are usually defined first and foremost, or stored in classes and accessed statically.
define('DEBUG_DETAILS', true);
function onError($msg, $details) {
    $msg = array('status'=>'error', 
                 'message'=>$msg);
    if( defined('DEBUG_DETAILS') && DEBUG_DETAILS ) {
        $msg['details'] = $details;
    }
    die(json_encode($msg));
}

// try to use the specific request method, and always sanitize!
$name = filter_var($_POST['Name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

/* Best to put this into a separate file, but not necessary, of course.
    Handling MySQL errors should fail a bit more gracefully in a "live" environment,
    such as setting the 'error' field to your $output array to 'true'.
*/
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or OnError('database connection failed', mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("MYDB") or OnError('database selection failed', mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT burnedCalories FROM Exercise WHERE Name='$name'");

if(!$sql){
    // clear the $output by assigning an array
    onError("The query failed.", mysql_error());
}

// set the status
$output['status'] = 'result';

// otherwise... perform usual loop
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[] = $row;

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

When you return a JSON result back to, well, anything, it's helpful to make sure the structure of the JSON string has similar members.

If your query is successful:

```
{
  status: 'result',
  {
    data: [
      'bench press': '900kCal/hr'
    ],
    [
      'pullup': '1100kCal/hr'
    ]
  }
}
```

And if not:

```
{
  status: 'error',
  {
    data: [
      'reason': 'Database error.'
    ]
  }
```

This way, when you go to extract the data on the device, page, whatever your end-result is, you have one format to follow, i.e. `getReason()`, `getResultCode()`, etc.